# Function Encapsulation Efficiency in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a large set of objects, and I need to be able to do some complex stuff with each object, so I have some fairly long functions.

In general, is it better to put the long functions in the class that they'll actually be used in (`GreatObject`, below) for proper encapsulation, or is it better for efficiency to put one function in the collection class (`GreatSet`, which will only ever have one instance)?

```
class GreatSet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.great_set = [] # Will contain a lot of GreatObjects.

    def long_method(self, great_object): # Is this function better here?
        [Many lines of code]

class GreatObject(object):
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params

    def.long_method(self): # Or here?
        [Many lines of code]
```

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: In general, it belongs with the object.

How may objects will be instantiated at a given time? How long is long? Long method is a code smell. Perhaps you should consider refactoring. Then, if still you are concerned about cost of instantiation do some testing of different implementations.

Comment: There could be up to 400 objects. There are a few methods—let's say altogether they are 300 lines of code. I'm not sure how Python handles this sort of thing, but that could be the equivalent of 120000 LOC, right?

Comment: @PProteus totally wrong - the code (the executable bytecode compiled from your sources) is __of course__ shared between objects, you __don't__ have one instance of the  "long_method" function's code for each instance xD

Comment: Thank you, Bruno. That seems like the better way to do it, but I have practically no knowledge of that level of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in both cases, `long_method` will belong to it's class (there will be a single `long_method` function per class, shared by all instances), and in both cases looking up `obj.long_method` will create a new `Method` instance for each lookup, so wrt/ "efficiency" (whatever it's supposed to mean) it won't make any difference. Also, unless you need maximum time and space performances - in which case a lower level language might be a best choice - you should really feel more concerned with proper design and maintainability than with maximum raw performances.

So, if `long_method` is supposed to work on `GreatObject` it *might* belong to `GreatObject`, *but* it depends on the respective responsabilities of those classes, what `long_method` really do, and  which application layers `long_method`, `GreatObject` and `GreatSet` belong to. If for example `GreatObject` and `GreatSet` both belong to the domain model and `long_method` do presentation-related stuff then obviously `long_method` belongs neither in `GreatObject` nor `GreatSet`.

Finally, as PartialOrder mentions in his comment, "long" functions are most often a code / design smell. Sometimes a function has to be "long enough" because it has do something complex - and even then you can usually refactor it into smaller functions (eventually into methods of a distinct class if those functions need to share state) -, but quite often a long function means it's just doing too many things.